# How to change Button on fetch response in react native?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Based on my response returned from server i want to change the button upon the status of field `friends_status` from the below response

```js
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "type": "314",
    "status": "200",
    "message": "Successfully found the profile"
  },
  "neighbourProfile": [{
      "friends_status": "210",
    },
    {
      "friends_status": "217",
    },
    {
      "friends_status": "219",
    },
    {
      "friends_status": "200",
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to change the button text as well as the button.How do i replace  button with an image

Updated:

```js
       if(neighbours.friend_status == '219'){
          <Button color={'#00BFA5'} title="Add"
          onPress={console.log('clicked')}/> 
       }
       else if(neighbours.friend_status == '208'){
          <Button color={'#ffffff'} title={"Add"} onPress={console.log('clicked')}/>
       }
       else if(neighbours.friend_status == '216')
       {

           <TouchableOpacity>
           <Image source={require('../Images/ic_reject.png')}/>
           <Image source={require('../Images/ic_request_accept.png')}/>
           </TouchableOpacity>

       }
       else if(neighbours.friend_status == '221'){

           <TouchableOpacity>
           <Image source={require('../Images/ic_reject.png')}/>
           <Image source={require('../Images/ic_request_accept.png')}/>
           </TouchableOpacity>

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `<Image />` as a `<Button />`, you can just place an image with wrapping `<Touchable />`:

```js
<View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {}}>
    <Image source={{uri: YOUR_IMAGE_URI}} />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
```

`<TouchableWithoutFeedback />` (and other Touchables) with content in it, is very much simular to `<Button />` with custom content.

Check [TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html), [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html), [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html) to pick one that suit your needs.

Comment: `if(neighbours.friend_status == '216')
      {
       return(
       <TouchableOpacity>
       <Image source={require('../Images/ic_reject.png')} style={{width:10, height:10}}/>
       <Image source={require('../Images/ic_request_accept.png') style={{width:10,height:10}}}/>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       )
      }` i've tried like this but got error

Comment: your second `<Image />`'s `source` does not have proper end of curly braces `}`

Comment: `if(neighbours.friend_status == '219'){<Button color={'#00BFA5'} title={"Add"} onPress={console.log('clicked')}/> }  else if(neighbours.friend_status == '216')  {  <TouchableOpacity> <Image source={require('../Images/ic_reject.png')} style={{width:10, height:10}}/><Image source={require('../Images/ic_request_accept.png')} style={{width:10,height:10}}/></TouchableOpacity> }` This is my updated code

Comment: Where you put these code? it looks not right, can you update inside your question. If that expression is inside *jsx*, you shouldn't use `if`. if not inside `jsx`, you should use `return`.

Comment: See Conditional Rendering section in document https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: so instead of using if what do i use? How do i change my code?

Comment: in jsx it would be `{ neighbours.friend_status == '219' && <Button /> }` `{ neighbours.friend_status == '216' && <Button /> }` just list them one by one.

Comment: @anu please read this **Inline If with Logical && Operator**. it would really benefit coding life. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create your own button component, you can pass your friends_status data as a props to the component than you can do this:

```
renderButtonContent(){
if (this.props.friend_status === xxx) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
} else {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text> add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

}

if my answer isn't clear feel free to ask any question to me. And you can also catch new props value with:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
```

}